# Constrained quadratic programming with positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, quadratic-programming, positive-semidefinite

I am facing the following problem:
$$\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{z}{\text{minimize}}
& & \textbf{z}^T \textbf{Q} \textbf{z} + \textbf{b}^T \textbf{z}\\
& \text{subject to}
&& \textbf{Az } \leq  \textbf{d}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$

where $\textbf{Q}\geq 0$, this is, positive semidefinite. The dimension of vector $\textbf{z}$ is $3$ and the constraint matrix $\textbf{A}$ has $8$ rows.

The Lagrangian would look like:

$$L(\textbf{z},\lambda) =  \textbf{z}^T \textbf{Q} \textbf{z} + \textbf{b}^T \textbf{z} + \lambda^T(\textbf{Az } -  \textbf{d}) $$

Replacing with the corresponding values I would get:

$$L (x_1, x_2, x_3, \lambda) = x_1^2 +x_2^2 + (1-|h_1|)x_1 + (1-|h_2|)x_2 + \lambda_1(-x_1+x_3 - h_1) + \lambda_2(-x_1 -x_3 + h_1) + \lambda_3(-x_2+x_3 - h_2) + \lambda_4(-x_2-x_3 + h_2) - \lambda_5 x_1 + \lambda_6 x_1 - \lambda_7 x_2 + \lambda_8 x_2$$

I must note that $h_1$ and $h_2$ are constants.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is obtaining the dual problem but that implies the use of the pseudo-inverse and I do not know if it is possible to avoid it.

Comment: I know no dual that employs the pseudo inverse. Why don't start with the lagrangian?

Comment: Mmm... Can you be more precise?

Comment: You have asked how to solve the problem using the lagrangian. Have you already formed the lagrangian? Would you add it to your post?

Comment: Yes, I will edit my question and add everything in there.

Comment: Do you mean $\lambda^T( Az-d)$? Well, just find a critical point, that's $\nabla_z L(z, \lambda) = 0$ with $Az \le d$, $\lambda \ge 0$ and $\lambda_i ( a_i^T z - d_i) = 0$. Since the problem is convex, every critical point is also optimal.

Comment: Yes sorry.
But that critical point with $\nabla_z L(z, \lambda) = 0$ require to use the inverse of $Q$, that's the main problem here.

Comment: well you have the other equations... also for you example you can compute the pseudo inverse pretty easily. But it won't help much. In general the pseudo inverse is pretty useless when inequality constraints are involved.

Comment: why can't you use a standard convex package to solve this?

Comment: Because I would like to implement my own solver

Comment: @m33n algorithmic solver involves combinatorial or barrier techniques and is much more complicated...

Comment: You are certainly not "required" to use the inverse of Q, as you claim above. One simply needs to find solutions to the KKT equations that present themselves---and with a singular Q, it means there are likely multiple solutions. Any technique you want to use to obtain those solutions is fine.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with your statement

Comment: What is the question?